# Cauchy Product proof- actual

Tags: combinatorics

I have a generating function $v(x)= a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots$  and I have to show that the coefficient of $x^n$ in the product $[v(x)]^2$ is the sum $a_la_k$ over all pairs k and l such that $k + l = n$. I cannot use the Cauchy Product as justification as we never officially discussed it in class. It's pretty obvious as it really simplifies down to the collection of like terms but I have no idea where to begin in formalizing this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Then how are you defining $v(x)^2$ to being with?

Comment: Just multiplication. V(x)^2 = V(x)V(x)

Comment: Sure, and how do you define multiplication of powerseries?

Comment: Well since they are generating function and we aren't really concerned with convergence, wouldn't we just multiply them like polynomials? So the sum over i greater than 0 of ai times the sum over j greater than 0 of aj is the sum over i,j greater than 0 of aiaj